# Odd placement of DatePicker in TextBoxFor Html helper tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, twitter-bootstrap-3, razor-pages

I want to add html Datepicker in my textbox razor markup. But it places the "dd/mm/yyyy" in bottom of the box(as shown in the [Image of the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDnAb.png)). I want this datepicker "dd/mm/yyyy" at the left center (not too much towards bottom). Below is my razor markup for reference.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth ,new {type="date", @class="form-control"})
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/padding).Here is an example.

```
<style>
    #DateOfBirth {
        padding: .375rem .75rem;
    }
</style>
```

result：

[image]